# MVVM - Menu View with Preview View (Shared ViewModel) approach

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, viewmodel, datacontext

I've just started my journey with MVVM and WPF and I need an advice to solve my problem or rather guide me towards right solution.

Link to image: https://s12.postimg.org/md0h6fv3x/Simple_App.png
[image]

## Description (what I want to achieve):

- View A is a menu (UserControl) with ListBox and DataContext: V.ObservableCollection
- View B is a preview to selected item from View A ListBox
- View A & B are loaded from MainWindow

### What is simpliest and cleanest approach to achieve that?

1. I was thinking about sharing the same ViewModel with View A&B.
   Create a SelectedItem property in ViewModel and then put it MainWindow's resources and bind datacontext to View A & B

   - Is it valid approach? Will that VM be updated properly in both views if it get changed?
2. Somehow bind View's A listbox SelectedItem to View B preview mode but don't know how.

Comment: MainWindowViewModel which references all VMs bound at the top window level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use only one `ViewModel`.
   Eg; Pseudo code :

   ```
   public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
     public ObservableCollection<Employee>{get;}          

     /* provide change notification in ChosenItem */
     public Employee ChosenItem{get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Use this `ViewModel as DataContext` for both Views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I the thing I wanted it to get deeper guidance on the second part: Use this ViewModel as DataContext for both Views.

Comment: @Chomik You need list to show in left view, and a chosen item to show its preview in right one, and both are present in `ViewModel` class.

Comment: I already have that list but I need clean solution how to share common ViewModel with two+ Views. How can I set the same ViewModel as DataContext to those Views?

Comment: @Chomik Those are not two views, u r mistaking them as two.

Comment: anyway I think I get it working, I divided MainWindow onto two columns and set DataContext of this grid to shared ViewModel and it works :) I hope it's good way to do it! Thanks for help

Comment: @Chomik of course it is. Forget about Views. Start logically building ur ViewModel, and rest will follow.